# Differentiabilty of a complex valued function

Tags: complex-analysis

The function $f(x+iy)=x^2-y^2+2i|xy|$ is differentiable in the closed first and third quadrants, because there the function becomes $z^2$ and at all other points of the complex plane $f$ is not differentiable (since CR equations don’t hold). May I know if I am correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is not complex differentiable on $\{x=0\land y\ne 0\}$ because for $h\in\Bbb R$ we have $$\lim_{h\to 0\\ yh>0}\frac{f(iy+h)-f(iy)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0\\ yh>0}\frac{h^2-y^2+2i\lvert yh\rvert+y^2}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0\\ yh>0}h+2iy=2iy\\ \lim_{h\to 0\\ yh<0}\frac{f(iy+h)-f(iy)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0\\ yh<0}\frac{h^2-y^2+2i\lvert yh\rvert+y^2}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0\\ yh<0}h-2iy=-2iy$$

Likewise, $f$ is not complex differentiable on $\{x\ne 0\land y=0\}$ because for $h\in\Bbb R$ we have $$\lim_{h\to 0\\ xh>0}\frac{f(x+ih)-f(x)}{ih}=\lim_{h\to 0\\ xh>0}\frac{x^2-h^2+2i\lvert xh\rvert-x^2}{ih}=\lim_{h\to 0\\ xh>0}ih+2x=2x\\ \lim_{h\to 0\\ xh<0}\frac{f(x+ih)-f(x)}{ih}=\lim_{h\to 0\\ xh<0}\frac{x^2-h^2+2i\lvert xh\rvert-x^2}{ih}=\lim_{h\to 0\\ xh<0}ih-2x=-2x$$

Cauchy-Riemann prove that $f$ isn't complex differentiable on $\{xy<0\}$.

$f$ is complex differentiable on $\{xy>0\}$ because there it coincides with the holomorphic function $z^2$. I leave to you to prove that $f$ is complex differentiable at $0$ with $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: Great, may I know that on what context you mentioned real differentiability? Partial derivatives?

Comment: @mathlover So apparently now holomorphic at a point means complex differentiable in a neighbourhood of that point... Whatever, I changed the terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your statement is correct. The function $f(x+iy) = x^2 - y^2 + 2i|xy|$ is differentiable in the closed first and third quadrants of the complex plane. In these quadrants, the function simplifies to $z^2$, which is a well-known differentiable function.

In all other points of the complex plane, the function $f(x+iy)$ does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann (CR) equations, which are necessary conditions for complex differentiability. Therefore, at those points, the function is not differentiable.

Comment: You are just repeating the OP's arguments.

Comment: @AlexM. This answer is wrong.